# Adaptive subdivision missing in my 2.78

Tags: modifiers

OK I might be doing it wrong, but I installed 2.78 and I cant find Adaptive subdivision, help?

Comment: You may have to activate experimental features first...  see this: http://gappyfacets.com/2016/10/06/blender2-78-adaptive-subsurf-microdisplacement-experiment/

Comment: Thanks!!..you have no idea  how many files of 2.78 I downloaded  over and over again. haha!

Comment: and also ensure you have the cycles render engine selected

Comment: You also need to make sure the SubSurf Modifier you want to use adaptive subdivision with **comes LAST in the modifier stack**. It makes sense when you think about it (how could subsequent modifiers possibly know what to do with adaptive data?) Anyway, i just encountered this and was confused for a moment as to why using Cycles with the Experimental Feature Set was still not enough to make the Adaptive option appear. Commenting in case others find this helpful.